# Please help in Zend Db Select

Tags: zend-framework, select

I want to write this query via zend db select

SELECT * FROM `bookmarks`
 INNER JOIN `urls`
 ON urls.url_id = bookmarks.url_id WHERE (bookmarks.bmk_id = '2') AND (bookmarks.user_id = 1)

Please tell me how to write? I am asking this because the method I am using to write this query is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need to do. It's absolutely textbook as described on in [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html)

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('bookmarks')
             ->join('urls', 'urls.url_id = bookmarks.url_id')
             ->where('bookmarks.bmk_id=?', 2)
             ->where('bookmarks.user_id=?', 1);
```